# create a map with extensible key values

Tags: java, dictionary

I would like to create a map with extensible key values.

Currently I have a common project which has some enum.
In my main project in which I have included the common project as a dependency, I have a map which uses the enum as the key: `Map<SomeEnum, String>`

I would now like to be able to have some sort of Map where I can extend SomeEnum to create a project specific set of values and then use this in the Map instead.
This is to force the developer to only use a key from predefined variables - this is why I have not used `Map<String, String>`

I know that enums can't be extended, so any other solution would be appreciated also.

The alternative as far as I can see - if this is not possible - is to have a `Map<String, String>`, but then include some kind of project specific validation on the Strings that are in the map to ensure it is part of some enum (ie some predefined variable set).

Thanks for reading. I hope this made sense.
Looking forward to the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map<YourInterface,String>` is the solution. Make your `enum` implement `YourInterface`.

Comment: Very clever. It does mean however, that I can't have a default set of variables in my common code, which I would like to have.

Comment: If you're sure that you need the keys to be from just one enum, go for http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper class that takes `SomeEnum` as constructor parameter. Save it to the field and render it `final`. Then, use this Wrapper as the `Map` **key**. Similar functionality can be achieved with *inheritance*, but the *Effective Java* from Joshua Bloch advises us to prefer *composition* over *inheritance*.

Just makes sure to implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods to compare against this enum.

```
public class EnumWrapper<T extends SomeEnum> {

    private final T fEnum;

    public EnumWrapper<T>(SomeEnum enum) {
       fEnum= enum;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return fEnum.hashCode();
    }

    @Override boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof EnumWrapper))
            return false;

        EnumWrapper other= (EnumWrapper) o;
        return this.fEnum.equals(o.fEnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: null check is not needed if using `instanceof`

Comment: How are you able to extend SomeEnum where SomeEnum is of type enum? I got compile time errors when I tried your code - "cannot convert from SomeEnum to T".
Furthermore, enum is a java keyword right? so java wont accept this as a variable name. 
Maybe I've misunderstood this completely that java 7 is able to do this? I'm on java 6.
Thanks

Comment: @darijan - enum can't be extended, so where's the extensibility here? How does an enum wrapper help at all in this case? eg `map.put(new EnumWrapper(SomeNewEnum.SOME_VALUE), "some_value");` will throw compiler error.

Comment: Then explain better what how do you want to use the map.

Comment: And no, enums cannot be extended in java.

Comment: @darijan sorry if i did not explain properly. I will use the map in my main project (which has the common project as a dependency). In my main project which is a webapp, I will be passing some data in headers via spring controllers. The headers map will then be processed and put into a map ready to be passed on to another application to do some logging. I will have a number of applications that use the common project with some common headers. However, there may be a chance whereby I would want to extend this list of headers for a particular project only. I hope this clarifies better. Rgds.

Comment: Its still confusing me. How do you connect headers and enum from the original question? I see that those two are closely related somehow, but I cannot have a grasp on it. And could you provide the code that is supposed to put new values in that "headers" map and fetch it.

Comment: using the request object in the controller, I call `String projectType = request.getHeader(SomeEnum.projectType.toString())` and put the value of this into a map: `map.put(SomeEnum.projectType, projectType);`

Comment: In any case, I Think I prefer the interface solution, though it does have it's limitations. Thanks a lot for your input @darijan